# Evaluate the limit inf of $\cos(n^4+n+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I want to calculate $\liminf\cos(n^4+n+1).$ In fact, I don't know how to proceed. I know that $\liminf\cos(n)$ is $-1$, but I have no idea if this will help me. So, I am asking if someone has an idea for the solution

Comment: That's a tricky question. In principle, it would be sufficient to show that the sequence of fractional parts $\left\{\frac{n^4+n+1}{2\pi}\right\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. It's known that $\left\{n^4\theta\right\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ for irrational $\theta$, but the proof uses the fact that the numbers $n^4$ form a (non-lacunary) multiplicative semigroup, so it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: the limit inf, is it -1?

Comment: @farruhota Your argument isn't valid. $\liminf \frac1n=0$ but $\frac1n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @farruhota do you have a proof that it is not? Numerical evidence and other heuristics seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt, got it, it may get arbitrarily close...